# Java Android project real device deployment takes too much time after Kotlin library integration

Tags: android, kotlin, android-library

I have android Java and Kotlin different projects. I converted the existing Kotlin project to library by making this below changes in gradle,

```
//apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        //applicationId "com.example.xxxxxxxx"
....
}
}
```

and i have deleted the intent filters of the library project,

```
<activity android:name=".view.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/MySuperTheme" >

</activity>
```

When I do file->invalidate cache and restart then clean rebuild and deploy to real device it takes more than 10min
it gives below error message,

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:
[0] '/Users/panchanathantharsan/StudioProjects/xxxxxxx/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'device '0123456789ABCDEF' not found'
```

After the first run its deploying fast. every time when clean, rebuild and deploy is very slow.

This is my main project gradle,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.apollographql.apollo'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.1'


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kaleSystems.kalePos"
        minSdkVersion 25
        //noinspection OldTargetApi
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
        // for view binding:
        // viewBinding = true
    }


    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    useLibrary 'android.test.mock'
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation files('libs/poi-excelant-3.14-20160307.jar')
    implementation files('libs/poi-ooxml-3.14-20160307.jar')
    implementation files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14-20160307.jar')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.6'
    implementation files('libs/httpcore-4.2.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpclient-4.2.3.jar')
    implementation 'androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.felHR85:UsbSerial:3.3'
    implementation 'com.github.douglasjunior:android-simple-tooltip:0.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.0'
    implementation project(path: ':reportModule')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation files('libs/kaleprintsdk-release.aar')

    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:1.7.1'

    //graphql
    implementation 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-runtime:2.2.0'
    implementation "com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-android-support:2.2.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.6.0'


}
```

this is the library gradle,

```
//apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.apollographql.apollo'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        //applicationId "com.example.kale_cloud_reports"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        packagingOptions {
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
        // for view binding:
        // viewBinding = true
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
    }

    apollo {
        generateModelBuilder = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.72'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
//    implementation'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.8"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"

    //graphql
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.6.0"
    implementation "com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-runtime:2.2.0"
    implementation "com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-coroutines-support:2.2.0"

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. This is slowing down the development process.
Thank you.

NOTE: What ever action i do deploy to emulator is normal and fast. no delays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Successfully sorted out the issue after fighting for days,

Created a new sample project and added the Kotlin library project its working smooth and fast.

Compared the both main project gradle configurations and found `android.enableD8=false`
is the one causing the issue.

Please do read more about enableD8 from official link at here https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/next-generation-dex-compiler-now-in.html

making it true did the magic and all sorted and application is running smoothly for all builds.
`android.enableD8=true`

If any one stuck like this make use of it. Check the gradle.Properties file and make the changes.
By default in android studio after 3.0 version it's set to be true.
Somehow it was modified in my case.
cheers.